# missing section title in ps but not in dvi

Tags: latex

A have the document with 23 figures and 46 tables (appendix to journal article). There are 23 sections created in the exactly same manner. When viewing compiled dvi everything is in order, but after creating ps file from the dvi one of the section title is missing. Producing pdf from dvi doesn't help. What may be the problem? I can give source file if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there images near the section title that is missing?  What format are the images in?  Does removing those images fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex :)
All the images in the document are eps files located just after each \section tag. The particular image had 'angle' option set to '270'. When I rotated the image in inkscape and removed 'angle' option the problem disappeared.
How can one explain such behavior?
Apparently there are two more figures with the 'angle=270', but there are no problems with that.

regards
chriss

Comment: Better to edit your original question than post fake answers here.

Comment: Oh, and sounds like your image has a funny bounding box and is overlaying the text, but it's impossible to tell without seeing it.

Comment: I didn't know what the details where, but I had to think it was the images because they are always a source of layout problems in tex.